# étale morphism (Morphismes étales), étale covering (Revêtements étales)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I needed to read about étale morphism (Morphismes étales), étale covering (Revêtements étales). I would like to know in which Grothendieck book or seminar I could find these definitions I quoted above. I know these definitions are in simpler places, however I'm interested in a corollary that I found in SGA 1. So, I'd like to "drink" straight from the source the settings I need for the corollary. So my question is simple, but only those who have experience can answer it. 
I have no experience with EGA or SGA. So I want to do as Ravi Vakil said: "You may think that you need to know everything in order to move forward, but this is not true. Learn what you need, do some reading for fun, and do no more."

Comment: You ask for the source of the definitions you quote, but you don't quote any ….

Comment: Also, surely SGA 1 itself, "[Revêtements étales and groupes fondamentales](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203)", is the starting place to look for the definition of an étale cover.

Comment: You may also try: Milne's Étale Cohomology (Princeton Univ. Press), for étale morphisms, Chapter 1 Sect. 3 and for coverings Chapter 2, Sect. 1. The standard Grothendieck reference is EGA IV. Vol. 4, Sections 17 and 18, but be aware that they rely on lots on the previous parts.

Comment: A word of warning: while I think everyone agrees on what étale morphisms are, the definition of an étale covering may vary. For instance, the definition of SGA1 (étale+finite) does not assume surjectivity, but I am pretty sure some people do.

Comment: See the polished version that supersedes SAG1, namely EGA IV 1st and 4th tomes that are available at numdam.org.